# Build Array from Input Fields question

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, array

I have a series of input fields sets:

```
<input type="text" name="people[name]" />
<input type="text" name="people[lastname]" />
<input type="text" name="people[email]" />

<input type="text" name="people[name]" />
<input type="text" name="people[lastname]" />
<input type="text" name="people[email]" />

...
```

and I am looking for a way of storing the values as an array like the one following

```
{ people: { name: xxx , lastname: yyy, email: zzz }, 
          { name: xxx , lastname: yyy, email: zzz },
          { name: xxx , lastname: yyy, email: zzz },
          ...
}
```

I will use update_post_meta(); to save the values.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT

```
// CALLBACK
<?php
function show_people_box($post){
$metas = json_decode(get_post_meta($post->ID,'people',true));
?>
<?php 
$hiterms = get_terms('people', array('orderby' => 'slug', 'parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' =>false)); 

?>
<?php foreach($hiterms as $key => $hiterm) { ?>
<h2 style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $hiterm->name; ?></h2>
<table width="100%">
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'people',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'tax_query' => array(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'people',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => $hiterm->term_id
)));
?>
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query->have_posts()){
$query->the_post();
?>
<?php 
$children = get_children(array('post_type' => 'people', 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ));
if($children) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><input name="people[name]" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="people[lastname]" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="people[email]" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<?php

$args_2 = array( 'post_type'=>'people','post_parent' => get_the_ID() );
$query_2 = new WP_Query($args_2);
while($query_2->have_posts()){
$query_2->the_post();
?>
<tr>
    <td><input name="people[name]" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="people[lastname]" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="people[email]" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
} else {

?>
<tr>
    <td><input name="people[name]" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="people[lastname]" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input name="people[email]" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}
?>
<?php
} wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<?php
}

// SAVE
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_people_box' );
function save_people_box(){

foreach($_POST['people'] as $key => $value){
$peoples[$key] = $value;
}

global $post;
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'people', json_encode($peoples) );

}
```

I hope it helps, in my attempt to simplify my question I removed some html tags. Thanks for all your help again.

Answer (score 1):

If two fields are named `people[name]`, only the last value will be sent with the form. To be completely reliable, you'll need to use an id for each person you're collecting details on:

```
<input name="people[0][name]">
<input name="people[0][email]">
<input name="people[1][name]">
<input name="people[1][email]">
...
```

Use an incrementing counter in your while loop to do this (`$i`):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    ...
    ?>
    <input name="people[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]">
    <?php
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

You can use the empty array key format (`[]`) only if you don't need to link other fields together.

```
<input name="people[name][]" type="text">
```

You'll only receive non-empty field values, so empty fields will get tossed and your array key will get messed up. Consider the following situation:

```
<input name="people[name][]">
<input name="people[email][]">
<input name="people[name][]">
<input name="people[email][]">
```

If a user only filled out the second name field, the second name would have an array key of `0`. You would have no way of linking the second name to the second email.

In the following situation:

```
<input name="people[][name]">
<input name="people[][email]">
```

Each new named field will be given a unique key in the index, so the email field would be at `$_POST[1][email]`.

Answer (score 0):

create an array from your form fields `$_POST['people']` data use foreach loop to get and create array of `$_POST['people']` data and then save array of data in post meta filed, do so like this

```
foreach ($_POST['people'] as $key => $value) {
    $peoples[$key] = $value;
}

update_post_meta($post_id, 'peoples', $peoples);
```

Comment: Please explain this answer in more detail. Why does this work, for example?

Comment: @s_ha_dum asker want to create an array from form fields and want to save in post meta as an array.

Comment: I know what the OP wants. Summarizing the question doesn't explain the answer.

Comment: @Anjum thanks for your answer, it works perfectly when I don't provide names to my fields (ex: people[]) but when I do it (people['name']) saves just the last item of the array. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: can you paste your complete code here.

Comment: @Anjum BTW, after checking the saved data this is what im getting, a bit different than how i needed.

{"0":"name","1":"lastname","2":"email",...}

rather than, {name:xxx,lastname:yyy,email:zzz},{name:xxx, lastname:yyy,email:zzz}...

Comment: @Efrain please paste your complete code here, so i can understand what you need to do.

Comment: Sorry @Anjum, I didn't read the last message asking for the code. Let me get home and will post it. Apologies